# PHP T_OBJECT_OPERATOR | Variable Set

Tags: php, oop

Working on a project of translating website and I had chose this [solution](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/30/easy-php-site-translation/)
.
I'm trying to accomplish something like :

```
$VAR1 = $translate->__('Word_To_Translate');
```

This, not works for me since, the result is directly shown in stdout of the webpage. Even so when trying to call `$VAR1` no result is returned.

Comment: Switch the `echo` for a `return`, if that's what it's using (you haven't shown the relevant code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easily possible with the class you've mentioned.

If you wish to edit the class so it'll return the value instead of `echo`ing it, you can edit `class.translation.php`, replace the two occurances of `echo $str;` with `return $str;`, and replace `echo $this->lang[$this->language][$str];` with `return $this->lang[$this->language][$str]` (simply changing `echo` to `return` on both instances).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response,

in many places I'am using the following logic:
    `$guest="<li><a  class='flat-white-btn transition' href='/?mode=signup' >$VAR1</a></li>";`

Want to echo the result of $VAR1, in this mater.

Answer (score 0):

//$VAR1 delegating
`$VAR1 = $translate->__('Word_To_Translate');`

//class.translation.php
`class Translator {

private $language    = 'en';
    private $lang       = array();

```
public function __construct($language){
    $this->language = $language;
}

private function findString($str) {
    if (array_key_exists($str, $this->lang[$this->language])) {
        return $this->lang[$this->language][$str];
        return;
    }
    return $str;
}

private function splitStrings($str) {
    return explode('=',trim($str));
}

public function __($str) {  
    if (!array_key_exists($this->language, $this->lang)) {
        if (file_exists($this->language.'.txt')) {
            $strings = array_map(array($this,'splitStrings'),file($this->language.'.txt'));
            foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
                $this->lang[$this->language][$v[0]] = $v[1];
            }
            return $this->findString($str);
        }
        else {
            return $str;
        }
    }
    else {
        return $this->findString($str);
    }
}
```

}`

Switched the **echo** for a **return**

Thank you very much **uri2x** && **Rizier123**.

For the moment looks that it is working solution.

Best wishes !